# Unable to install basemap package anaconda

Tags: package, anaconda, matplotlib-basemap

I am trying to install the basemap module in my Anaconda environment. When I try to do this, the following message appears.

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - basemap
  - zict
Use "conda info " to see the dependencies for each package.

I am not able to delete the 'zict' package. Is there any way I can install the basemap package in another way?

Thank you very much!

Comment: what was the command you've ran?

Comment: I have tried two different things
1. I have tried to apply the basemap module using the environment page in the anaconda navigator
2. I have tried to run the command: "conda install basemap" in the navigator prompt.
Both gave the same error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue, which was resolved following advice from https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/tvtFcG5-0oA

What worked for me (Python 3.6 on 64-bit Windows 10) was using the basemap package built by conda-forge instead. So from the conda terminal, run:

conda install -c conda-forge basemap

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

for me that terminal command kept failing till I updated All of Anaconda first

conda update --all  (this will take hella time)

then i ran:

conda install -c anaconda basemap

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble with that. Fortunately, I solved the problem. Follow below steps;

1. Create a new environment in anaconda.
2. Install Jupyter Notebook and launch it. If it works, turn it off.
3. Change your anaconda environment in your terminal.
4. Try installation commands below:

   1. `conda install basemap`
   2. `conda install forge ...`
   3. `pip install basemap`