# Can't install basemap (python)

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

I am trying to install basemap in python to plot some maps. But I am having some troubles installing the basemap package.

I have tried all the suggestions from

[Unable to install basemap package anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50100549/unable-to-install-basemap-package-anaconda)

Regardless of the code, I typed in python (i.e. conda install basemap; conda update --all; conda install anaconda ...) I always receive the following error message.

Can anyone provide any guidance on how I should proceed? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: try first `conda install quandl` then use `conda install basemap`

Comment: i tried conda install quandl, the same message appears.